# Magento 2: How to sort product on Category page by entity id in desc order?

Tags: magento2, product, category, product-sorting

I need to show all the newly created products on top. So need to arrange all the products according entity id in descending order

Comment: Please, show your collection?

Comment: what do you mean by "product page"? the admin grid? the category in the storefront?

Comment: sorry it was category page on frontend

Answer (score 1):

Easiest and cleanest solution would be creating an "afterPlugin" on `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\Source\ListSort::toOptionArray` and adding `$options[] = ['label' => __('Entity ID'), 'value' => 'entity_id'];`

Once you did this, you can select the value in "Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Product Listing Sort by" to apply it to all categories by default.

Comment: Can you please explain more in detail this? where to put this file, how to declare? Thanks!

Comment: as stated in the answer, you are supposed to create an afterPlugin. the documentation explains how to do this

Comment: Does this work with Elastic?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with ElasticSearch for me.